# woocommerce rest api product image in localhost

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, woocommerce

i have a woocommerce site(https://example.com) and i need to control this site's products using my wordpress on localhost (xampp) ...
i can create product using rest api of woocommerce but i cant set an image for this product.every time i send create product request using rest api i receive this error :

stdClass Object ( [code] => woocommerce_product_image_upload_error [message] => Error getting remote image [http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/6550-min.jpg](https://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/6550-min.jpg). Error: A valid URL was not provided.. [data] => stdClass Object ( [status] => 400 ) )

How can i fix this?

Comment: Did you check if this image exists on your local machine?

Comment: yes this image is exist on my localhost , i uploaded this image using wordpress media

Answer (score 2):

Wordpress rejects calls made to a different host.
Localhost is a different host than example.com, even if they reside on the same machine.

You can use the `http_request_host_is_external` filter to allow localhost:

```
add_filter( 'http_request_host_is_external', 'allow_localhost', 10, 3 );
function allow_localhost( $allow, $host, $url ) {
  if ( $host == 'localhost' ) {
    $allow = true;
  }
  return $allow;
}
```

You should add the above code in your theme's `functions.php`.